# Wordpress site loads slowly - slow server response time?

Tags: wordpress, webserver

my website ([www.scaredycut.com](http://www.scaredycut.com)) loads very slowly. According to [a load test](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/WD9c7/www.scaredycut.com), the initial "wait" is a long bottleneck. It ranges between 600 and 1900 ms.

Google's PageSpeed Insights test says:

> In our test, your server responded in 0.59 seconds. There are many
>   factors that can slow down your server response time. Please read our
>   [recommendations](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/Server) to learn how you can monitor and measure where your
>   server is spending the most time.

[Google's recommendations](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/Server) don't tell you how to measure or get to the bottom of the problem. Does anyone have any suggestions as to where I should start? Should I contact my host?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: 1900 ms is only 1.9 seconds. It may have to do with loading your images.

Answer (score 0):

You need a complete [PageSpeed](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http://www.scaredycut.com/) overhaul and are you on cheap cloud hosting? Cuz your actual .com is taking over 2 seconds to load on its own without files.

Install w3 total cache and see how it does after activation vs without.

Comment: I did the PageSpeed tests - my post outlines what Google told me. The site is the Pro Plan on ipowerweb (http://www.ipower.com/ipower/web-hosting/unix-pro-plan.bml).

Comment: I would begin with doing what it says. Minifying the CSS and JS. I use W3TC. But your hosting co should help you to get that .com loading faster than 2 seconds I hope.